# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Slim\Views\Twig

Tags: twig, slim-4

I keep getting Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Slim\Views\Twig::__construct() must be an instance of Twig\Loader\LoaderInterface, string given ...

Code is:

```
require DIR .'/vendor/autoload.php'; 
$container = new Container(); AppFactory::setContainer($container); 
$app = AppFactory::create(); 
//$twig = new Twig('./templates',['cache'=> false]); 
//$twigMiddleware = new TwigMiddleware($twig, $container, $app->getRouteCollector()
->getRouteParser(), ''); 
//$app->add($twigMiddleware); 
//$routeParser = $app->getRouteCollector()->getRouteParser();
//$twig = new Twig(DIR.'/templates'); 
//$twigMiddleware = new TwigMiddleware($twig, $container,$routeParser); 
//$app->add($twigMiddleware); 
$container->set('view', function(){ return new Twig('./templates', ['cache'=>false]); });
$app->add(TwigMiddleware::createFromContainer($app));
```

I'm using

```
  "require": {
    "slim/slim": "4.3.0",
    "slim/psr7": "^0.6.0",
    "php-di/php-di": "^6.0",
    "slim/twig-view": "3.x-dev"
}
```

I tried different options (commented). Can anybody help me? I can't figure this out
Thanks

Comment: `$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('/path/to/templates');`

Answer (score 0):

this is about the version on twig you can solve changing the code

```
    //set view container before create app
    $container->set('view', function () {
        return Twig::create('views', ['cache'], false)
    })

    //and instead adding $twigmiddleware code this at the same line of $twigmiddleware
    $app->add(Twigmiddleware::createFromContainer($app));
```

this wiill work on new version of twig